# updating parent id count will have not effecting from trigger helper class

Tags: apex, trigger, roll-up-summary

I am updating one Parent To another parent on contact object. child record count will not work.

**Helper**

```
public void performOnAfterUpdate(List<contact> lstcon, Map<Id, Contact> oldMapCon) {
        for(contact con : lstcon){
            if(con.AccountId != oldMapCon.get(con.id).AccountId && con.AccountId != null){
                AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
                system.debug('---list--- '+ con.AccountId +'---OldMap--- '+oldMapCon.get(con.id).AccountId);
            }
        }
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, My_Contact__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : AccountIds];
        for(Account acc : accList){
            acc.My_Contact__c = acc.Contacts.size();
        }
        update accList;
    }
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger countRecord on Contact (After insert, After update) {
    contactTriggerHandler handler = new contactTriggerHandler();

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        handler.performOnAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        handler.performOnAfterUpdate(Trigger.New,Trigger.OldMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to be more specific about the issues you are facing?

Comment: i have a custom field on Account object My_Contact__c (this is number type) its shows count of no. of child records. when creating new contact my code will work but when i update one contact with another parent then count will have no effects.

Comment: You are completely missing `delete` and `undelete` case...Just use [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) and don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your code it seems to me that, If Contact Parent is changed from `Account-A` to `Account-B`, you are adding `Account-B` value into the `AccountIds` list. Now you have to add `Account-A` into the list so that you will get updated contact count for `Account-A`.

**Updated code will be like this:**

```
if(con.AccountId != oldMapCon.get(con.id).AccountId && con.AccountId != null){
            AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
            AccountIds.add(oldMapCon.get(con.id).AccountId); //add this line
            system.debug('---list--- '+ con.AccountId +'---OldMap--- '+oldMapCon.get(con.id).AccountId);
        }
```